How to get rid of a popup menu if opened by mistake on linux
I have a Treeview with a bound context menu which appears when I right click on the mouse.   Sometimes I right click by accident. How do I get rid of the context menu without adding an item to close it?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

MEMBER_COLUMNS = (
    ('first_name', 'First name', 120),
)


class MainFrame():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = self._member_tree()
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.context_menu = tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label='Delete', command=self._delete)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def _member_tree(self) -> ttk.Treeview:
        tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root, selectmode='browse', height=5)
        tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        tree.bind('<Button-3>', self._show_context_menu)

        tree.column("#0", width=0)
        col_list = tuple([col[0] for col in MEMBER_COLUMNS])
        tree['columns'] = col_list
        for col in MEMBER_COLUMNS:
            (col_key, col_text, col_width) = (col[0], col[1], col[2])
            tree.heading(col_key, text=col_text)
            tree.column(col_key, width=col_width, anchor=tk.W)

        for member in ['John', 'Fred']:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values=member)
        return tree

    def _show_context_menu(self, event):
        self.context_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def _delete(self):
        print('delete')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainFrame()


If you left-click outside of the context menu it goes away. Do you need something other than that to happen?

@JRiggles It doesn't go away

What OS are you on? When I click away from the context menu on Windows 10 it disappears.

You should be able to either click outside of the menu, or press the escape key.

@BryanOakley @JRiggles  I tested on LInux and it really stays open. I can't close it with ESC nor clicking outside of the menu. Popup stays open as top element  on screen even when I switch to other window - so I see it all the time.

I found this but I didn't test it python - Python3 Tkinter popup menu not closing automatically when clicking elsewhere - Stack Overflow

code in previous link doesn't work for me on Linux. The only idea which work - assign events to treeview with function unpost - self.tree.bind('<Button-1>', self.close_menu) and def close_menu(self, event=None): self.context_menu.unpost(). I don't know why but it doesn't work when I use lambda in bind(). BTW: it may need to assign to root if you want close it when you click outside treeview - self.root.bind('<Button-1>', self.close_menu)

correction: click and escape works for me on Linux when I use tk_popup() instead of post() - self.context_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

@JRiggles The other question does give a solution, but judging by these comments it might be a Linux issue
